# How can I see the SQL ActiveRecord generates?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to check a few queries generated by ActiveRecord, but I don't need to actually run them.  Is there a way to get at the query before it returns its result?

Comment: Note that with rails 3+ , you can just tack on a `to_sql` to the query:  `Posts.where(:something => foo).to_sql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of these articles should help you do what you want.

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/8/watching-activerecord-do-it-s-thing

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/1/31/more-on-watching-activerecord

Comment: Those still run the queries, but they solve the problem I was really after, since the queries (a) are idempotent and (b) don't take too long.

Answer (score 2):

i think it's buried in:

```
construct_finder_sql,
```

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_frm/thread/38c492e3939dd9bf/?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

tail -f log/development.log

Works in default settings or when you set your logger level to DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

Jamis' article is outdated, or at least doesn't work my Rails app (possibly due to some other reason with a 3 year old 30,000 line app).  However this works in a console any time:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)
```